# Mysterious Undefined control sequence errors

Tags: errors, pdftex, texmaker

I am using the texlive distribution on Ubuntu 14.04 and use the Texmaker IDE.

I implement latex using the quickstart function configured to

pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex -> View pdf

I have recently found that some of my documents start throwing up a lot of

```
"! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ..."
```

type errors. There is no reason for this to be occurring as far as I can see as I did not change anything significantly and it worked before.

I solved the problem simply by copy/pasting the code into a new file with a new name.

However I am curious why the errors occurred and how I can prevent this occurring in the future?

Any ideas?

Comment: May be residual auxiliar files?

Comment: It appears to be so. If I delete all the auxiliary files it works. But why did the errors appear in the first place. I had run latex on the document innumerable times and it worked fine with each time the auxiliary files being overwritten. Why did it suddenly stop working?

Comment: Did you delete also the temp files generated by `bibtex`?

Comment: Do you mean the .bbl file and the .blg files? If so, yes.